# Excel macro input box to enter text, new sheet and its name

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I need some help in inserting a MSG box that prompts for text to be entered. For example i will be recording a vlookup but the text should be entered before the formula so that it can be searched. I also need to add new sheet and change its name using input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example:

```
Sub InputDemo()
    Dim s As String
    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter text", Type:=2)
    MsgBox "you entered " & s
End Sub
```

Comment: That was very helpful, i have a bit modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Sub inputboxandsheetname()

```
 'To add text box
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")
'To add new sheet
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    'To rename the new sheet
ActiveSheet.Name = myValue
```

End Sub